# OperationalError: no such table: entries while "init_db()" already inserted in flaskr.py

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

Here is a part of my flaskr.py,
I tried to run it on 127.0.0.1:5000 but it gave me a Internal Error.
Then I checked the error_log, which telled,

```
File "/var/www/html/flaskr/flaskr.py", line 66, in show_entries (model,sn,user,status))
OperationalError: no such table: entries "
```

Here are my codes:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
app.config.from_envvar('FLASKR_SETTINGS', silent=True)

def init_db():
"""Creates the database."""
    with app.app_context():
        db = get_db()
        with app.open_resource('/var/www/html/flaskr/schema.sql', mode='r') as f:
            db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
        db.commit()


def get_db():
"""
Opens a new database connection if there is none yet for the
current application context.
"""
    top = _app_ctx_stack.top
    if not hasattr(top, 'sqlite_db'):
        sqlite_db = sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])
        sqlite_db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
        top.sqlite_db = sqlite_db
    return top.sqlite_db

@app.route('/')
def show_entries():
    db = get_db()
    with open('/var/www/html/flaskr/hardwarelist.txt') as fl:
        for eachline in fl:
            (model,sn,user,status)=eachline.strip().split(',')
            db.execute('insert into entries (model,sn,user,status) values (?, ?, ?, ?)',(model,sn,user,status))
        fl.close()
    cur = db.execute('select model,sn,status,user from entries order by id desc')
    entries = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template('show_entries.html', entries=entries)

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    init_db()
    app.run()
```

I thought the error caused from my "init_db" function did not run well ,so I can't get the table of entries.
But here were no error report about init_db , what should I do to figure out this question & fix it?

Update:
There is my schema.sql:

```
drop table if exists entries;
create table entries (
id integer primary key autoincrement,
model text not null,
sn text not null,
status text not null,
user text not null    
);
```

Comment: Can you also post your code showing how you set up the database?

Comment: @coralv  Sure, I put my schema.sql , but don't sure if it was what you mean.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately, I am not sure what's causing your problem.  Upvoted in the hopes of catching the attention of someone who can provide an answer.

Comment: @coralv Thank you all the way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happened to solve the problem by deleting these two lines.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run()
```

and remain:

```
init_db()
```

Then everything run perfectly.However don't know how it caused.....
Answered it just for note & share.

Answer (score 1):

What helped me in the the same scenario where the db file wasn't created correctly is to run from terminal.

```
flask init-db
```

and then run the app again

```
flask run
```

This updated the example db file correctly.